# How to join firebase data with the newest angularfire and fire util?

Tags: firebase

I have a list of categories and a list of products:

```
{
  categories: {
    'myCategoryId': {
        name: 'my category name',
        products: {
            'first': true,
            'second': true
        }
    }
  },
  products: {
    'first': {
        name: 'my product name',
        categoryId: 'myCategoryId'
    },
    'second': {
        name: 'my second product name',
        categoryId: 'myCategoryId'
    }
  }
}
```

In my sidebar I want to show a joined list of categories with product names so I need some joined structure like:

```
{
  categoriesWithNames: {
    'myCategoryId': {
        name: 'my category name',
        products: {
            'first': {
                name: 'my product name'
            },
            'second': {
                name: 'my second product name'
            },
        }
    }
  }
```

I know I can do this with Firebase util and AngularFire, but I've tried few different methods and I cannot grasp the concept of joining denormalized data in Firebase. Can anyone help me?

### Code

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["firebase"]);
var FBURL = "MYFBURL";
var FBEVENTS = {
    'deleted':'child_removed',
    'added':'child_added'
};

myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$firebase',
    function ($scope, $firebase){

        var base = fb(FBURL);

        function fb(url) {
            return new Firebase(url);
        }

        function fbChild(attrs) {
            return $firebase(typeof attrs === "string" ? base.child(attrs) : base.child(attrs.join("/")));
        }

        function $a(fbChild) {
            return fbChild.$asArray();
        }

        function $o(fbChild) {
            return fbChild.$asObject();
        }

        var products = fbChild('products');
        var categories = fbChild('categories');

        $scope.products = $a(products);
        $scope.categories = $a(categories);

        $scope.products.$loaded().then(function(){
            $scope.categories.$watch(function (snapshot) {
                console.log('snapshot is', snapshot);
                if(snapshot.event!==FBEVENTS.deleted) {
                    var foundCat = $scope.categories.$getRecord(snapshot.key);
                    foundCat.products = _.map(foundCat.products, function (val, key){
                        if (val !== true)
                            return val;
                        return $scope.products.$getRecord(key);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Show the code of what you tried please.

Comment: here's how i tried to join them http://jsfiddle.net/5hhd9y1x/ i know there's a better way with fire utils but i don't know how.

Comment: Please read a bit about MCVE's (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as I now had to spend time reconstructing one based on the fiddle: http://jsbin.com/vefabo/1/edit?html,js,output. Now that the code runs there, what is the problem you are having with it?

Comment: If I `console.log(foundCat);` after the call to `_.map` it shows a category with two products. That looks good to me, so as said before: what is the problem?